# Existence of a right adjoint functor of the inverse image via a morphism of schemes between the categories of quasi-coherent modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, adjoint-functors, pullback, pushforward, representable-functor

Let $f:X\to Y$ a morphism of schemes. It induces a covariant functor:
$$f^*:Qcoh(Y)\to Qcoh(X)$$
Which happens to be the inverse image. Now, fixing any quasi-coherent $O_X$-module N we can define another functor:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Qcoh(Y) @>>> \mathcal{S}ets\\
\\
M@>>>Hom_{O_X}(f^*(M),N)
\end{CD}
which, due to representable functor theorem, it is representable. Then, $f^*$ has a right adjoint, and it has to be the direct image $f_*$.

The problem I find now is that the direct image of a quasi-coherent sheaf it is not necessarily quasi-coherent, so there is something wrong, but I can not find where the error is.

Comment: The version of the theorem I was taught says that it has to be left-exact and to transform colimits into limits. What do you mean by infinite products? are you talking about direct-products?

Comment: I guess what happens is that there is always a right adjoint in the realm of quasicoherent sheaves, but it only coincides with the direct image functor for nice morphisms. Remember the direct image is only a right adjoint in the category of $\mathcal{O}$-modules.

Comment: But that sounds quite unsettling... there must something wrong

Comment: I've tried to construct it. If i am not wrong, by taking the maximal cuasicoherent submodule of the direct image sheaf, I can define a right adjoint for the inverse image between quasi-coherents. There must be something wrong, because this right adjoint is a subject of study in case I am right...

Comment: I don't find it unsettling, this seems like business as usual. For example, there exist infinite products of quasicoherent sheaves, but they are not the same as products in the category of all $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Your description of the right adjoint also seems to be correct at a glance.

Comment: But after a night of thinking, maybe not every quotient of a qc module is qc, and then my explaniation fails...